# Can you send a variable containing html from module file to template

Tags: html, module, drupal, twig

I'm migrating drupal 7 to drupal 8 and there is a custom module that contains a lot of custom html code in the .module file. I understand that modules in drupal 8 requires a .html.twig file that contains the html while the .module uses a hook to send variables to the .html.twig

Is there a way to send a variable containing HTML in the .module file to be rendered by the .html.twig

.module code :

```
$var = <p>hello world</p>
```

.html.twig code:

```
{{ var }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but you have to add this param in twig.

```
{{ var | raw }}
```